# Can I get odoo 8 user's session from PHP?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am creating BI reporting tool for our business purpose in PHP which requires user authentication. I want to utilise Odoo ERP user's credentials to newly built PHP App. More likely, current user's session from Odoo ERP.

What I need?

- If user is logged-in on Odoo ERP, use same credentials to validate user for PHP App and take user to Report page else ask to login in PHP page and Vice Versa.

Is it possible to do this? I am using Odoo ERP V8

Answer (score 0):

it's possible you need to use XML-RPC  odoo's web services

https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html